# Debug applinks entitlements in final IPA in Flutter iOS app

Tags: ios, xcode, code-signing-entitlements

I have a Flutter app and the following file `ios/Runner/Runner.entitlements`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>aps-environment</key>
    <string>development</string>
    <key>com.apple.developer.applesignin</key>
    <array>
        <string>Default</string>
    </array>
    <key>com.apple.developer.associated-domains</key>
    <array>
        <string>applinks:nutmegapp.page.link</string>
        <string>applinks:web.nutmegapp.com</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

but for some reasons applinks still don't work.

I read that the Entitlements get populated in the IPA and I can debug them inspecting the content of `Payload/Runner.app/embedded.mobileprovision` file

In this file I see for example `aps-environment` and other settings but I don't see the `applinks` domain.

Any idea of why? Where can I verify that these entitlements are correctly passed to the final artifact?

Comment: maybe this link helps you: https://tanaschita.com/20220725-quick-guide-on-associated-domains-in-ios/

Comment: check and verify the validation of AASA in your server in the link : 
https://branch.io/resources/aasa-validator/#resultsbox

Comment: after check the valid AASA file delete your app in the device and reinstall it and check again

Comment: in developer mode you should add this query string to end of applinks: ?mode=developer

Comment: The setup is correct. But the entitlements get lost when building for release, this is the problem

Comment: how many have you entitlements? [YourProjectName] and [YourProjectNameRelease] ?

Answer (score 1):

Open your proejct in xcode:

[image]

after that, check the signing and compatibilities tab:

[image]

[image]

if you have "debug" and "release" and "profile" tab you should define "**applinks**" on each tab separately (You maybe have "debug" and "release" that is OK).
finaly you should have 3 entitlement in your project:

[image]

Runner.entitlements

RunnerRelease.entitlements

RunnerProfile.entitlements

check and verify the validation of AASA in your server with this link :
https://branch.io/resources/aasa-validator/#resultsbox

after check the valid AASA file delete your app in the device and reinstall it and check again

in developer mode you should add this query string to end of applinks: ?mode=developer

Finaly this link maybe helps you:
https://abhimuralidharan.medium.com/universal-links-in-ios-79c4ee038272

Comment: done all of this but it seems the entitlements are not correctly set