# deep link not supported with all apps

Tags: android, ios, deep-linking, universal-link

I set up deep links to my app

### Android

`AndroidManifest.xml`

```xml
      <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
        <data android:scheme="http" />
        <data android:scheme="https" />
        <data android:host="my-domain.com" />
        <data android:pathPrefix="/app" />
      </intent-filter>
```

`/.well-known/assetlinks.json`

```
[
  {
    "relation": ["delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls"],
    "target": {
      "namespace": "android_app",
      "package_name": "com.xx.xx",
      "sha256_cert_fingerprints": [
        "XX:XX"
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

### iOS

I added `applinks:my-domain.com` to `Associated Domains`

`/.well-known/apple-app-site-association`

```
{
  "applinks": {
    "details": [
      {
        "appIDs": [
          "xxx.com.xxx.xxx"
        ],
        "components": [
          {
            "/": "/app/*",
            "comment": "Matches any URL with a path that starts with /app/."
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

So the deeps links are working for example if I open my url `https://my-website.com/app/...` from an sms or slack the app will be open but from messenger or instagram I have the issue, the browser is oppened and not the app

Doing test with

```
npx uri-scheme open "https://my-website/app/..." --ios
// or
npx uri-scheme open "https://my-website/app/..." --android
```

Is working on both android and iOS

Is it better to use deep link than universal links ? Maybe there is a better support, but I will lose the user which didn't download the app

I also added those tags https://developers.facebook.com/docs/applinks/add-to-content but it does not work from instagram not messenger

Comment: Have you take a look to Firebase Dynamic Link? It did miracles in my use case for handling a lot compatibility issues. https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links

Comment: check this steps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75999889/debug-applinks-entitlements-in-final-ipa-in-flutter-ios-app/76003500#76003500
and after check validation AASA you should delete your app and install again